# replace CanvasRenderingContext rectangles, shapes with svg images in browser Pacman game

Tags: javascript, html, svg, canvas

I'm trying to replace the pills in this browser game with svg images

https://codepen.io/hellokatili/pen/xwKRmo

At the top of the JS file, I entered the following (my approach is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3769883/2075859)):

```
var image = new Image()
img.src = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d2/Svg_example_square.svg";
```

There is a function called `drawPills` which draws the pills using CanvasRenderingContext rectangles.  As I understand it, the image I want to replace these rectangles with needs to be loaded before I can use it, so I replace the call to drawPills() with the following:

```
    image.onload = function() {
      map.drawPills(ctx);

    }
```

Then in the drawPills() function, I replace the rectangles with the image:

```
      ctx.drawImage(image, i, j);
```

Here's what my completed version of drawPills looks like:

```
  function drawPills(ctx) { 

    if (++pillSize > 30) {
        pillSize = 0;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < height; i += 1) {
        for (j = 0; j < width; j += 1) {
            if (map[i][j] === Pacman.PILL) {
              ctx.drawImage(image, i, j);
              /*                     ctx.beginPath();

                ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
                ctx.fillRect((j * blockSize), (i * blockSize), 
                             blockSize, blockSize);

                ctx.fillStyle = "#FFF";
                ctx.arc((j * blockSize) + blockSize / 2,
                        (i * blockSize) + blockSize / 2,
                        Math.abs(5 - (pillSize/3)), 
                        0, 
                        Math.PI * 2, false); 
                ctx.fill();
                ctx.closePath();*/

            }
        }
    }
```

No svgs are loaded, however.  Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hard to see what you really did with only this, can you include at least **your** full `drawPills`? Also note that this exact svg has no size defined, expect weird behaviors when using drawImage with it, and even complete failure on at least Firefox. See [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34706891/canvas-draw-image-issue-on-firefox-works-well-in-chrome/34713521#34713521) about this issue.

Comment: @Kaiido   I included the `drawPills` function

Comment: so first, *x* and *y* of *drawImage(source, x, y)* should be `j * blockSize` and `i * blockSize` respectively.

Comment: @Kaiido  Thanks, that makes sense.  I'm still not seeing the svg being drawn at all though.

Comment: Your first line defines `image`, but in the second line you use `img.src`. I am assuming you should start with `var img = new Image()`. Also, the source of the image is not secure (`http`). At least in codepen, the image will not load.

Comment: You should consider using a game engine: https://github.com/collections/javascript-game-engines

Answer (score 2):

While the images do not seem to be in the correct places I got the image loaded. I added this to the top of your code:

```js
function loadImage(url){
  let image = new Image()
  image.src = url
  return image;
}
var pill_img = loadImage("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d2/Svg_example_square.svg")
```

And replaced the code in the for loop of drawPills with:

```js
ctx.drawImage(pill_img, j * blockSize, i * blockSize, blockSize, blockSize)
//While you had the pills drawn to a different spot, this position got it closer than doing ctx.drawImage(pill_img, i * blockSize, j * blockSize, blockSize, blockSize)
//You can always shift it
```

This draws the image in the wrong places, but now we know it is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You define variable `image` then you set the `src` to a variable called `img`.

Also, if you try to load that image on an `https` page, your request will be blocked because you can not load unsecure content in `https` pages. Try changing `http` with `https` in your image request.